# Join Query Combining Two Tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I need to display 3 columns from table A and one column from table B. I used the following join query to combine them but not getting the value in the expected columns.
   example1 -this is working.(If I display one column from table A and one    column from table B it works)

```
SELECT
      tableA.col1(fkid),
      tableB.col1
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.fkid = tableB.pkid;
```

I need to display 3 columns from table A and one column from table B  the below query is not working.

```
SELECT
     tableA.col1,
     tableA.col2,
     tableA.col3,
     tableB.col1
FROM tableA 
FULL JOIN tableB
ON tableA.fkid = tableB.pkid;

  Original query:
select device.name,device.description,   device.fkphonetemplate,phonetemplate.name from device inner join phonetemplate   ON device.fkphonetemplate=phonetemplate.pkid;
```

Result:

```
description         fkphonetemplate                         name
Nikhil (nkalantr)   10ce46f6-615d-4605-9f42-454225df5647    ARRAY(0xc7153b0)
```

Expected result should be:

```
description         fkphonetemplate                         name
Nikhil (nkalantr)   10ce46f6-615d-4605-9f42-454225df5647    Standard 7960 SCCP
```

I don't get name from device table in the result and the name from phonetemplate table shows something as Array0X... but I need to get the name of phonetemplate like Standard 7960 as shown in expected result.
Can you refine my query or suggest what's wrong with the 2nd query?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Have you tried replacing the `FULL JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`? Some sample data and expected result would be nice.

Comment: For the first query I get the following output which is correct.                                   fkphonetemplate                             Name
027e79d3-bb6d-40c3-b48a-8dfaab890904 Standard Cisco TelePresence MX200
10ce46f6-615d-4605-9f42-454225df5647 Standard 7841 SIP
10ce46f6-615d-4605-9f42-454225df5647 Standard 7841 SIP
10ce46f6-615d-4605-9f42-454225df5647 Standard 7841 SIP

Comment: For the 2nd query- this is the original query. select device.name,device.description, device.fkphonetemplate,phonetemplate.name from device inner join phonetemplate ON device.fkphonetemplate=phonetemplate.pkid;                                               The result is                                                                                            description fkphonetemplate name
Nikhil (nkalantr) 10ce46f6-615d-4605-9f42-454225df5647 ARRAY(0xc7153b0) I don't get  the name instead I get something called ARRAy blah blah.

Comment: Yes, I tried both inner and full join and same result.

Comment: Kindly edit the question and post the sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason for you to using full join instead of inner join ? 
If no,try using inner join.

```
SELECT
     a.col1,
     a.col2,
     a.col3,
     b.col1
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
ON a.fkid = b.pkid;
```

Can you provide your database sample data , so we can clearly know what your need.

Comment: Yes I tried both inner join and full join.Same result. I have edited the question with my requirements.